# Rename a file in GitKraken

Tags: gitkraken

Is there some way to perform a `git mv` operation entirely within the UI of GitKraken? I want the file history to be preserved despite the name change, and my students are terrified of using the command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe that is currently possible since there's no file browser built into Gitkraken. So you can't display all the files in a repo in order to do basic things like see how many revisions there are of each file, open them in an editor, rename them, etc. Hopefully they'll add a file browser tab at some point.

So for pretty much any file operations, you have to do the operation externally, using a file browser like Windows explorer, Nautilus, etc., or the dreaded command line. :)

If you rename the file externally to Gitkracken, then Gitkracken will see the rename and commit it as a rename, so the file history will be preserved. After committing you can see the full history on the command line using "git log --follow file".

Within GK the history is also available, but is kept separately for each of the past file names so is harder to see. If you use the fuzzy finder to bring up the history for a file, there are clickable links to the previous names of the file.

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for, but appears to be a correct answer nonetheless.

Comment: "Gitkracken will see the rename and commit it as a rename, so the file history will be preserved" - this is not true. Git does not store rename-operations at all - the act of detecting renames is entirely performed by the diff algorithm your git config is using (`--diff-algorithm`) after the commit has already been made. Remember that git is radically different from svn and that is is *not* a "file-based" source-control system like SVN or TFS.